# Reduce postgresql log verbosity

Tags: postgresql

Every time I invoke a parameterized query I get too much output in the log file. For example, when inserting 3 users into a table I get the following log output:

```
2013-10-29 06:01:43 EDT LOG:  duration: 0.000 ms  parse <unnamed>: INSERT INTO users (login,role,password) VALUES
     ($1,$2,$3)
    ,($4,$5,$6)
    ,($7,$8,$9)
2013-10-29 06:01:43 EDT LOG:  duration: 0.000 ms  bind <unnamed>: INSERT INTO users (login,role,password) VALUES
     ($1,$2,$3)
    ,($4,$5,$6)
    ,($7,$8,$9)
2013-10-29 06:01:43 EDT DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'guest', $2 = 'user', $3 = '123', $4 = 'admin', $5 = 'admin', $6 = '123', $7 = 'mark', $8 = 'power user', $9 = '123'
2013-10-29 06:01:43 EDT LOG:  execute <unnamed>: INSERT INTO users (login,role,password) VALUES
     ($1,$2,$3)
    ,($4,$5,$6)
    ,($7,$8,$9)
2013-10-29 06:01:43 EDT DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'guest', $2 = 'user', $3 = '123', $4 = 'admin', $5 = 'admin', $6 = '123', $7 = 'mark', $8 = 'power user', $9 = '123'
2013-10-29 06:01:43 EDT LOG:  duration: 4.000 ms
```

Notice, that the whole query appears three times - for parse, for bind and for execute. And the complete set of parameters appears twice - for bind and for execute.

Note, that this extra verbosity is only present when running parameterized queries.

Here is my config:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\data>findstr log_ postgresql.conf
# "postgres -c log_connections=on".  Some parameters can be changed at run time
log_destination = 'stderr'              # Valid values are combinations of
log_directory = 'pg_log'                # directory where log files are written,
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log' # log file name pattern,
log_file_mode = 0600                    # creation mode for log files,
#log_truncate_on_rotation = off         # If on, an existing log file with the
#log_rotation_age = 1d                  # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
#log_rotation_size = 10MB               # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
#syslog_facility = 'LOCAL0'
#syslog_ident = 'postgres'
log_min_messages = notice               # values in order of decreasing detail:
log_min_error_statement = error # values in order of decreasing detail:
log_min_duration_statement = 0  # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements
#log_checkpoints = off
#log_connections = off
#log_disconnections = off
#log_duration = off
#log_error_verbosity = default          # terse, default, or verbose messages
#log_hostname = off
log_line_prefix = '%t '                 # special values:
#log_lock_waits = off                   # log lock waits >= deadlock_timeout
log_statement = 'all'                   # none, ddl, mod, all
#log_temp_files = -1                    # log temporary files equal or larger
log_timezone = 'US/Eastern'
#log_parser_stats = off
#log_planner_stats = off
#log_executor_stats = off
#log_statement_stats = off
#log_autovacuum_min_duration = -1       # -1 disables, 0 logs all actions and

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\data>
```

So, my question is how can I reduce the verbosity of the log for parameterized queries without affecting the other queries? Ideally, I would like to have the query SQL and its parameters logged just once.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible out of the box.  You could write a logging hook and filter log entries.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue I was facing before Above config which you have mentioned just change `log_min_duration_statement=-1` ( disable) the query will be once only logged

BUT you have enabled the duration it will just log duration 3 times but not the query
Like

```
2013-10-29 06:01:43 EDT LOG:  duration: 0.000 ms 
2013-10-29 06:01:43 EDT LOG:  duration: 0.000 ms
2013-10-29 06:01:43 EDT LOG:  execute <unnamed>: INSERT INTO users (login,role,password) VALUES
     ($1,$2,$3)
    ,($4,$5,$6)
    ,($7,$8,$9)
2013-10-29 06:01:43 EDT DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'guest', $2 = 'user', $3 = '123', $4 = 'admin', $5 = 'admin', $6 = '123', $7 = 'mark', $8 = 'power user', $9 = '123'
2013-10-29 06:01:43 EDT LOG:  duration: 4.000 ms
```